# How can I flag a compiler warning when an object does not use one of its class methods?

Tags: java, annotations

I have a class called SQLProvider, it contains methods for both opening and closing a SQLite database connection. Using annotations or another approach, is it possible to flag a compiler warning if the open method is used without also calling close?

```
{
    SQLProvider provider = new SQLProvider();
    provider.open()
    // display a compiler warning unless provider.close() is also invoked in this code block
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure it would be the best approach but you can make your class implement [Closeable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) interface . As per the Eclipse [documenatation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcompiler%2Fref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm), Eclipse will display warning :

> When enabled, the compiler will issue an error or a warning if a local variable holds a value of type 'java.lang.AutoCloseable' (compliance >= 1.7) or a value of type 'java.io.Closeable' (compliance <= 1.6) and if flow analysis shows that the method 'close()' is not invoked locally on that value.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no such facility in the standard Java toolchain.

In addition to the Eclipse compiler warnings (see New Idiot's answer), some static code analysers can warn you about this:

- For PMD, the [`CloseResource`](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.2.6/rules/design.html) design rule covers this (or at least some subcases ...)
- FindBugs can also do this; e.g. [FindBugs - "may fail to close stream" when using ObjectOutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434323/findbugs-may-fail-to-close-stream-when-using-objectoutputstream)

But the problem is these warnings are more or less heuristic.  They only understand certain standard idioms for reliably closing resources.  If you do it some other way (which is still provably reliable) they are likely to produce a false warning.  This is not necessarily bad (because doing this a non-standard way is liable to fool / puzzle future readers!).  However the possibility of false positives may tempt developers to ignore or (worse still) suppress the warnings.

There are a couple of additional issues:

- These checks *may* give a false negative for resource objects that have a `close()` method without implementing `Closeable` or `AutoCloseable`.
- These checks *may* give a false negative for `Closeable` / `AutoCloseable` resource objects where the `close()` operation is a no-op; for example, `StringWriter`.

These issues *may* explain why the standard Java toolchain doesn't support this.